# Firestore backup with cron jobs

Tags: angular, firebase, cron, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I have used this [**firestore-backup-restore**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-backup-restore) for firestore backup. It is working fine. But could you tell me how can I use schedule it using cron jobs or like so? I don't have any previous experience with cron job though. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

This is what I did using above api. This is working fine. But how to schedule it?

> firestore-backup-restore --accountCredentials
>   D:\Backups\Firestore/budget-my-reno-firebase-adminsdk-lh8d5-5bfad6f090.json
>   --backupPath /backups/myDatabase

Answer (score 2):

If you are using any Linux distro you can use CRON and learn how to config it for your needs. I could recommend you [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-cron-guide) or refer you to the [cron man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).

If you are on Windows, you could go for any of the cron-like tools of windows. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975/8340339) you have some examples.

Comment: I have to set this on Mac. Any clue?

Comment: It works just like linux. Anyway, [this](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html) is an read about cron for mac with some examples.