# VBA code to run on 10 minute intervals only during work hours

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I want my code to run on 10 minute intervals throughout the work day, but stop when the work day is over. Currently my code uses

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "!Module1.Refresh3"
```

but it causes problems as it continues to run all night.

Comment: [This](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/124093-application-ontime-run-function-every-10-minutes-between-7-00-00am-and-7-00-00pm) could be helpfull

Comment: What is the job you want to perform? Would a tool like the unix cron not be more suitable to a task which has to be performed throughout the day?

see **What is the Windows version of cron?**  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: You need to give a bit more clarification: do you consider a bank holiday a work day? (I suspect not). If not, then you need some more logic than just having it run during working day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
If Hour(Now) > 19 Then
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("12:00:00"))
End If
```

This would stop your code from 8pm onwards for 12 hours.
For clearification: As peakpeak mentioned, make sure you run this in your outer loop, so after every 10 minute interval these lines get evaluated.

Comment: The code should be in an outer loop, otherwise it'll only execute once at best