# How to schedule Check in and Out of files to SVN(sub version Control) from 12 different machines everyday

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

As I work for small firm and we are using SVN as version control system. 
  Now I am assigned with a task to automate the process of Check in the files every day at 8PM from 12 different machines from a Specified path(I can make it same path in all 12 different machines), commit only the changed files in the specified path.

This would help in case developer forget to upload his changes to SVN, it should be automatically taken care. I am not familiar with linux. Currently the need of the hour is on Windows. Also we use Jenkins in the organization for execution of batch files remotely.

Can some one help me on this,

Thanks in advance - 
Ram

Answer (score 0):

This seems very hacky... As a developer I have the one job before leaving to push my changes.
I would recommend training your colleagues to use the given tools appropriately instead of creating hacky solutions for a problem that imo must not exist.

Nevertheless if you do want to implement it you would need

- the machines running (or maybe start them via wake on lan)
- a way to connect to that machine e.g. setting up ssh-servers on all the machines and a way to address the machines (static IPs)
- alternatively execute your script directly on the machines, timing it with Windows Task Scheduler, AT or else ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/132975))