# How to make a Python code run automatically everyday

Tags: python, windows, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have written the following code to open a particular site.

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

I want to modify the code to ping the website twice a day without being using an always running code in the background (maybe with an infinite loop).

I'm using a Windows 10 system. I don't have root access.

I have done a little research and was unable to find anything satisfactory.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this SO  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron.

Comment: As you say, you don't have admin rights on this Windows computer. You're probably going to need to talk to the system administrator to see if they have an option for you.

Comment: Wanted to know if there is a way around, without the admin access.

Comment: this might be useful - https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7

Comment: @InAFlash That question still talks about running with administrator permissions. In this case, Raghvendra doesn't have admin rights on the computer, so won't be able to schedule a task using Task Scheduler.

Comment: mybad.. i read it as "with admin rights"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use github actions - there is a guide [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onschedule)

Comment: I'm able to schedule this on Github hosted runner. But now I need to modify the program to login into StackOverflow also.

Comment: There is a stack exchange api. Would that help? https://api.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

LINUX:

use Crontab or place your script in /etc/rc.local.

WINDOWS:

Use Task scheduler or use AT command similar to crontab in linux.

Comment: The question indicates the OS is Windows 10.

Comment: @dspencer Task Scheduler then.

Comment: I don't have root access.

Comment: @RaghvendraRao try this `crontab -u <username> -e`

Comment: As mentioned in the question I'm on a Windows system.

Comment: @RaghvendraRao For command-line usage, you can schedule with the AT command.Its very similar to crontab in linux.

Answer (score -1):

on Windows you can use Task Scheduler

Comment: I don't have root privilege on the system.