# Command schedule with IntelliJ

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, console, command, testcafe

I have the following command that I run with terminal in IntelliJ

```
testcafe chrome test.ts
```

Is there any way to make this command to be run at 11pm? I mean to schedule it.
I will be very thankful for you guys.

Answer (score 1):

A short answer is yes.

A longer answer is you don't want to do this in your IDE, but use other tools like [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

You don't mention what operating system you use, so it's difficult to be concrete here, on Unix and Linux system, you'll typically have cron installed and so you can use it for this task.

If you're using a Windows system, I recommend reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron), you will likely find an answer there.